# Passing collections of objects as parameters in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am completely new to VBA and I would appreciate some help with something that should be trivial.
I have the following code:

```
Sub sub1()
Dim buys As Collection
Dim sells As Collection
Set buys = New Collection
Set sells = New Collection


handleBuy rowCounter, buys, sells

End Sub




Sub handleBuy(ByVal rowNum As Integer, ByRef listBuys As Collection, ByRef listSells As Collection)
'do something here with the collections

End Sub
```

The above collections contain objects instantiated by a class I define.
When I try to run the above code I get a runtime error 424 "Object Required"
The error occurs where the call to the handleBuy takes place.
What am I missing here? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the issue is with rowCounter.  I do not see you define it anywhere and if you use Option Explicit then you need to define the variable.  Other than that I was able to run the code without issue.

Comment: I just ran your code - it works fine. Does _exactly this_ code produce the error on your machine? Or did you leave out something vital?

Comment: It turns out I just mistyped one of the variables in that subroutine.
Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

1. Define the `rowCounter` variable; or
2. Remove the `Option Explicit`

1 is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because since `rowCounter` is not `Dim`'ed as `Integer` (and in the absence of `Option Explicit`) is of the default type `Variant`.  Which is incompatable with the declared `Sub handleBuy(ByVal rowNum As Integer`

Solution: use `Option Explict` - this will help prevent this type of error
And declare `Dim rowCounter As Integer`

BTW, you *should* use `Long` rather than `Integer`